# clone an object's element and push to it's self

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, lodash

I have a object  A.

if I `JSON.stringify(A)`, I get this result:

```
{
    "OrderA": [{
        "orderId": "19",
        "serverId": 129,
        "description": "Apple",
        "status": "1",
        "details": ""
    }]
}
```

Now, I would like to clone it's own element and make a larger object like this:

```
{
    "OrderA": [{
        "orderId": "19",
        "serverId": 129,
        "description": "Apple",
        "status": "1",
        "details": ""
    }],
    "OrderA": [{
        "orderId": "19",
        "serverId": 129,
        "description": "Apple",
        "status": "1",
        "details": ""
    }],
     "OrderA": [{
        "orderId": "19",
        "serverId": 129,
        "description": "Apple",
        "status": "1",
        "details": ""
    }]
}
```

How to achieve this by using lodash/underscore/ or jQuery?

so far, I've tried jQuery.extend, lodash union, and didn't work.

Comment: That's not a valid object; the keys should be unique, such as `OrderA, OrderB, OrderC.....`.

Comment: Shouldn’t the structure be `"OrderA":[{…}, {…}, {…}]` instead of `"OrderA":[{…}], "OrderA":[{…}], "OrderA":[{…}]`?

Comment: @Xufox oh, I was just curious about how to clone object's element and it turns out that we can't have duplex keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object keys have to be unique, otherwise you overwrite the previously held data. See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/mu8za362/).

Here's how:

```js
var ALL = {
    "OrderA": [{
        "orderId": "19",
        "serverId": 129,
        "description": "Apple",
        "status": "1",
        "details": ""
    }]
};

['B','C','D'].forEach(function(letter,index) {
    ALL['Order'+letter] = $.extend(true, {}, ALL.OrderA);
});

console.log( JSON.stringify( ALL ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The object isn't being cloned here - OrderA, OrderB etc all reference the same object.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to create the object you are describing. You are repeating the property name `"OrderA"` in each case, which is not allowed. I suggest using a new array and push the objects inside instead of having a mapped object with property names. Something rough like this:

```
var A; //Your OrderA Object.
var B = jQuery.extend(true, {}, A),
    C = jQuery.extend(true, {}, A),
    D = jQuery.extend(true, {}, A);

var arr = [A, B, C, D];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to use a different key but this won't work?

```
var A = {
    "OrderA": [{
        "orderId": "19",
        "serverId": 129,
        "description": "Apple",
        "status": "1",
        "details": ""
    }]
};

var B = {};

for (var attr in A.OrderA[0]) {
  if (A.OrderA[0].hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
    B[attr] = A.OrderA[0][attr];
  }
}

A.OrderB = [B];

JSON.stringify(A);

{
    "OrderA": [{
        "orderId": "19",
        "serverId": 129,
        "description": "Apple",
        "status": "1",
        "details": ""
    }],
    "OrderB": [{
        "orderId": "19",
        "serverId": 129,
        "description": "Apple",
        "status": "1",
        "details": ""
    }]
}
```

Comment: If later on he changes A.OrderA attributes, that would change A.OrderB attributes as well because they share the same reference to the object.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and got 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined' error.

Comment: sorry, missed the array wrapper on OrderA. check the edit.